# Google Chrome Extension to Check domain Contents

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to check whether or not a domain contains a certain phrase or word with a Chrome extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sure is. By injecting a site with a content script you can manipulate (search) the DOM anyway you like.

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html

Comment: Yes, this is a pretty straightforward use-case. See the "sandwich" sample for details: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/samples.html#sandwich